# Storing expirable credits in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

It is easy to store user credit with an extra col in the user table, e.g. `user_credits`, now an extra requirement

- for each credit added to the  `user_credits` col, it will auto expire one year after if not being consumed.

Definitely I need an extra table for storing expiring information, e.g.

```
[table credits_history]
user_id
credits
used
created_at
```

So, when consuming credits, I need to

- check if the  `user_credits` is enough to consume
- loop all `credits_history` table for the user's credit which `used = 0 AND now - created_at < 1yr`, and set `used to 1`
- update the `user_credits`

Finally I need to set a daily cron job to update `user_credits` by looking at the `created_at`

Are the above approach reasonable? Or any standard way to handle the above requirements?

Answer (score 4):

Don't store things that you can compute unless it's too expensive to calculate. Assuming that the number of rows in `credits_history` per user is not too high, you can structure your queries in such a way as to check the sum of available credits:

```
SELECT SUM(credits-consumed) -- see more about "consumed" below
FROM credits_history
WHERE user_id=?
  AND created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

A nice side benefit of this approach is that you no longer need a cron job to maintain `user_credits`.

Consuming credits becomes a little tricky: you need to add a column showing the portion of the credit that has been used. Here is an example to illustrate this point. Let's say a user added these credits in his history:

```
created_on credits consumed
---------- ------- --------
05/06/2014   50        0
07/12/2014   70        0
12/01/2014   40        0
```

If you run the query above, you would get a sum of 160.

Now he wants to consume 90 credits. Your code should query all eligible credit records, order them from oldest to newest, and use as much credits as needed to cover the desired amount (i.e. 90)

```
created_on credits consumed
---------- ------- --------
05/06/2014   50       50
07/12/2014   70       40
12/01/2014   40        0
```

Now the query above would get a sum of 70.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows

TABLE: `USER (id,name,address,phone,etc)`
TABLE: `CREDIT_TYPE(id,description, expiration_policy, etc)`
TABLE: `USER_CREDIT(user_id, credit_type_id, activation_date, expiration_date)`

- A user has zero or many credits
- Each credit has some sort of expiration policy, rules, etx
- If the CURRENT_DATE > expiration_date, the credit is expired

The expiration date is set immediately based on the policy set forth on the credit_type

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think this is a normal approach.  Normally you would have a table like user_credits which can have multiple rows for each user, each such row has the REMAINING credit, and expiry date (I think I prefer expiry date rather than created_at, since you calculate it only once).   But then you would have a Transactions table which lists credits/debits (positive/negative credits).    Buying credits would create a transaction of that amount of credits being added.  Using credits would create a transaction of that amount of credits being deducted.  Expiring credits would just be another transaction of credits being deducted.  Each transaction also updates the remaining credit in user_credits.
The only annoying thing is that to calculate a user's current credits you have to go to user_credits and add up all of that user's rows.  Some people might track another value in the main user table to bypass it.

Expiring credits can be done through a cron job to tidy up that table.  Although if you want to be stingy you could check the expiry date at the time of the transaction as well to make sure nobody sneaks through just before the cron job.